# Is the sample mean an unbiased estimator of population mean in the presence of autocorrelation?

Tags: mean, autocorrelation, estimators, unbiased-estimator

I've seen previous questions here that the sample mean can be considered an unbiased estimator of the population mean. e.g.[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277699/is-the-mean-of-a-specific-sample-of-the-population-an-unbiased-estimator-of-the), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315053/why-not-any-random-variable-is-an-unbiased-estimator-of-the-population-mean).

While the examples seem to refer to independent sample points, it seems to me that their argument should also be true for autocorrelated data (or for that matter for any data). This intuition is further reinforced by discussion I have seen about regression and more complex models (mixed models), that seem to emphasize that autocorrelation or violations of independence influence the degrees of freedom and standard error of model coefficients but not the coefficients themselves. If we think of the mean as 'coefficient' (for example the intercept in an ANOVA) the rationale should apply to the mean.

However, I haven't found a proof of unbiasedness that incorporates autocorrelation, i.e. assuming $x_{t+1}= w_tx_t +w_{t-1}x_{t-1}+... + w_0x_0+ \epsilon$. Am I just being overly cautious or is there a set of data where the sample mean is not a good representative of the population mean?

Comment: Whether a sample mean provides an unbiased estimator for the population mean depends on how the sample is drawn. Are you interested in, for example, simple random sampling when the data is autocorrelated? Or a case where the sampling is autocorrelated?

Comment: I'd be interested in both since my general question is whether the sample mean is always an unbiased estimator of the mean overall. But if it's too much to answer both, let's imagine random sampling with correlated data.

Comment: A simple random sample provides an unbiased estimator for the mean (given that the population size is known) regardless of the structure of the data. There are many cases though where sample means do not provide unbiased estimators e.g. ratio estimators.

Comment: @num_39 A ratio estimator is not a sample mean, though.  Regardless, this question needs clarification concerning two things: (1) What is the sampling procedure? (2) What probability distribution should be used: the sampling distribution or some underlying model?  The question seems to refer to both of these approaches (*e.g.,* "autocorrelation" is a model construct) but the answers would be different.

Comment: Maybe I'm being imprecise in the language here, but imagine some price fluctuation data (say, hourly tesla stock values or bitcoin prices in USD). Usually, values at $t+1$ are close to values at time $t$. So even if autocorrelation is a model construct, what I'm trying to express is that "the fact that data values are so similar between one time step and the next implies that most models with a reasonable predictive capacity should account for that effect". And for sampling imagine a uniformly random sampling. I have data between $t_0$ and $t_f$ and  select t's at random.

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question because it seems predicated on a mathematical falsehood. In particular, suppose the random vector $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ models your $n$ data values and each component separately has expectation $E[X_i]=\mu_i.$ Then, *no matter what correlation its distribution might have,* it's still the case that $$E[(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n]=(\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_n)/n.$$ In particular, when the $X_i$ have common means $\mu_i=\mu,$ the right hand side simplifies to $\mu$ itself: the sample mean is unbiased. How, then, does your scenario differ from this model?

Comment: I think my question may have sounded more complex than it is. I just wanted confirmation of the fact that you stated above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, autocorrelation (or spatial correlation or ...) do not destroy the  unbiasedness of the sample mean as an estimator of population mean.

Expectation is a linear operator, so when you calculate the expectation of the sample mean by
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}  
  \E \left\{ \frac1n \sum_i^n X_i \right\} =\frac1n \left\{ \E X_1 + \E X_2 + 
     \dotsm + \E X_n \right\} = \dotsm
$$ The only thing you need to calculate to finnish is $\E X_i = \mu$, which
only involves the marginal distribution of the $X_i$`s, correlations or other aspects of bivariate or multivariate distributions are simply not used.

With (strong) correlations there might well be better estimators of the population mean $\mu$ than the simp,e sample mean, for example weighted means. But the sample mean is still unbiased.

**EDIT**

Added after user whuber`s comment below. The answer above is formal, let us look more closely at what can happen with a highly correlated time-series, if it is not long enough to mix well. With a very high correlation a time series might stay for a long time in a limited region of its state-space. For a simulated example I will use fractional Gaussian noise, which is defined as the increments of fractional Brownian motion. While the increments of the usual Brownian motion are independent, with the fractional case this is not true.

[image: Four series with simulated fractional Gaussian noise]

The theoretical mean of the simulated series is zero, but look how the red series is always above zero ... none of these four series are really exploring the full statespace.

Below the R code used:

```r
library(fractionalBM) # Not on CRAN, installed from github
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(7*11*13)

N <- 30; nSERIES <- 4

SERIES <- matrix(as.numeric(NA), nrow=N, ncol=nSERIES)

for (i in 1:nSERIES) SERIES[, i] <- fractionalBM::FGN(N, 0.95)

SERIES <- data.frame(SERIES, time=1:N)

plotdata  <- reshape2::melt(SERIES, variable.name="Y", id.vars="time")

ggplot(plotdata, aes(x=time, y=value, group=Y, color=Y )) + geom_line()
```

Note also that this problem can be difficult to detect with only limited data. Below a table of estimated (with R function `acf`) and known, theoretical autocorrelations (based on Hurst exponent 0.95 as used in the simulation). The estimation uses only one of the simulated series:

```r
est   the
 [1,]  1.000 1.000
 [2,] -0.176 0.866
 [3,] -0.206 0.800
 [4,]  0.320 0.767
 [5,] -0.086 0.745
 [6,] -0.187 0.728
 [7,]  0.037 0.715
 [8,] -0.089 0.704
 [9,] -0.180 0.695
[10,]  0.205 0.686
[11,]  0.011 0.679
```

First column is the estimated autocorrelations, which is effectively pure noise. Effective estimation of such strong autocorrelations needa much longer series.

Comment: This answer skirts around what seems to be the fundamental issue and could mislead readers.  An example might make this plain.  In a stationary, ergodic time series when the $X_i$ are strongly positively autocorrelated, their mean can be an unbiased estimator of the long-run mean, but it might be highly likely in any particular realization to differ significantly from the mean.  The problem is that expectation is averaging over a *model* distribution and not over the sampling distribution.

Comment: @whuber: See my edited answer

Comment: I appreciate the extra clarification @kjetilbhalvorsen, and I just want to confirm that I'm aware that highly correlated data, will take a long time sampling (and potentially a large sample size, if sampling is somewhat regular) to approach the real mean value. I'm fully aware that being "unbiased" just means approaching the real value of the population when sample size tends to infinity.

Comment: I struggle a bit with @whuber terminology (for me there are population parameters and there are sample parameters, and statistics is the effort/science of estimating the former from the latter). In the process, we can make assumptions about the nature of our data (distributions, models, etc.) to facilitate our inference, but I do not see how assuming a distribution is necessary for this question.

Comment: But overall, my doubt has been aswered in full thanks for the help!